# Query disregard previous declared condition in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem about my query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM requests 
WHERE date = '2014/05/18' AND payorTown = 'Malolos' 
   OR payeeTown ='Malolos' OR payorTown != 'Malolos' OR payeeTown != 'Malolos' 
ORDER BY typeOfAssistance`
```

I have something like that, but MySQL disregard the first condition which is the `date = '2014/05/18'` Im pretty sure that there is no record that match the same `date`. But the results comes up with many records found that match the condition `AND payorTown = 'Malolos' OR payeeTown ='Malolos' OR payorTown != 'Malolos' OR payeeTown != 'Malolos'`.

Is there any rules about declaring conditions in WHERE CLAUSE?

Answer (score 1):

You need organize your where criteria ,your current query is neglecting the and criteria like (where date and payorTown ---> or ) you need to separate you and criteria with or criteria by grouping all the ors in group (somecond or somecond or ...)

```
SELECT * FROM requests 
WHERE date = '2014/05/18' AND 
(
(payorTown = 'Malolos' OR payeeTown ='Malolos') OR 
(payorTown != 'Malolos' OR payeeTown != 'Malolos')
)
ORDER BY typeOfAssistance
```

Answer (score 1):

When combining AND & OR conditions, it is important to use brackets so that the database knows what order to evaluate each condition. (Just like when you were learning the order of operations in Math class!)

```
SELECT * 
FROM requests
WHERE date='2014/05/18 AND
(
 payorTown = 'Malolos' OR 
 payeeTown ='Malolos' OR 
 payorTown != 'Malolos' OR 
 payeeTown != 'Malolos'
)
ORDER BY typeOfAssistance
```

In your case, it doesn't make sense because the condition in the brackets would always return true. You might want to use `AND` somewhere in the brackets.

I guess, you are after something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM requests 
WHERE date = '2014/05/18' AND 
  (payorTown = 'Malolos' AND payeeTown ='Malolos') OR 
  (payorTown != 'Malolos' AND payeeTown != 'Malolos')
ORDER BY typeOfAssistance
```

**Explanation:**

Apart from the date condition, this query will select the records if it satisfies **one of the following** conditions:

1. payorTown **AND** payeeTown  is 'Malolos'
2. payorTown **AND** payeeTown  is not 'Malolos'

Answer (score 1):

`AND` binds harder (has higher precedence) than `OR`, so your condition is in effect;

```
WHERE date = ('2014/05/18' AND payorTown = 'Malolos') 
   OR payeeTown ='Malolos' OR payorTown != 'Malolos' OR payeeTown != 'Malolos'
```

That is, your date condition is only combined with `payorTown = 'Malolos'`, the matches coming from the other conditions are returned no matter the date.

I can only guess what you really mean to do with the query, but the solution is simply to use parentheses to override the default precedence, something like (the somewhat nonsensical);

```
WHERE date = '2014/05/18' AND 
   (payorTown =  'Malolos' OR payeeTown =  'Malolos' OR 
    payorTown != 'Malolos' OR payeeTown != 'Malolos')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM requests 
WHERE date = '2014/05/18' AND 
(payorTown = 'Malolos' AND payeeTown ='Malolos') OR 
(payorTown != 'Malolos' AND payeeTown != 'Malolos')
ORDER BY typeOfAssistance
```